# Getting 404 error on Login in Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

When I am trying to login in `Magento` project in my local server downloaded from live server, then I am getting 404 error on the Dashboard page.Its working fine on Live server.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed any extension?

Comment: If you not found any solution then please check: http://techzoom.org/fixing-magento-404-error-whoops-on-all-pages-admin-dashboard-after-login/

Comment: No, i have only installed project in my local server as given by client and it is working fine on live server.

Comment: Try it with log out and login.

Comment: Not working, tried many times.

Comment: Other menu working or not?